# How to call a td element by integer class name

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have some `<td></td>` elements as shown below.

```
<td class='2'>Hello</td>
<td class='3'>World</td>
```

I need to add style to this `<td>` by calling the class.
I have tried as below, but no changes are taking place.

```
<style>
.2, .3 {
    background-color: green;
}
</style>
```

I don't want to use id attribute.
I know that something is missing here, but can't quite figure it out!

Comment: you can not have number as starting in class names...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors

Comment: `.\32, .\33 { background-color: green; }`

Comment: @Alohci This did it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

CSS classes starting with numbers won't work, if that's what you actually do. Use words instead (letters a-z), underscores(_)  and hyphens (-) only.

Comment: ok, got it! Thanks